# Write a function to sum any 2 numbers in a list - Python

Tags: python, function

Could you please help to advise which part is wrong in this function when "The function should return True if any two numbers within nums sum up to target. Otherwise, return False."

Thank you so much for your help!

```
random.seed(a=13, version=2)
random_numbers = random.sample(range(1000000),k=10000) # generate 10,000 random numbers in [1, 1,000,000)

def pair_exists(nums, target):   
    for i in nums:
        for j in nums:
            if i != j and i + j == target:
                print (i,j)
                return True
            elif i+j != target:
                print (i,j)
                return False

print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 38109)) # SHOULD RETURN TRUE
print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 13538)) # SHOULD RETURN FALSE
```

I got a result as

```
271590 271590
False
271590 271590
False
```

Comment: is target 543180?

Comment: You *always* return true or false on the very first try, which ends the function immediately.

Comment: You `elif` means you will always return on the very first number tested. Just remove you `elif` clause and put the `return False` outside the `for` loop. Note: python has `itertools.combinations()` which would replace your `for` loops, e.g. `for i, j in itertools.combinations(nums, r=2): ...`

Comment: Yay it works @AChampion. Thank you so much!

Comment: Write code that executes your pair_exists() function, once for each number within the target_numbers list. How many of these values return True? Add this to the mystery number (e.g., if 5 of the numbers cause pair_exists() to return True, then add 5 to the mystery number).

```random.seed(a=12, version=2)
target_numbers = random.sample(range(100000), k=10)
num_found = 0

print(pair_exists(random_numbers,target_numbers))```
I got false for this question. is false a correct answer?
Thank you

Comment: @AChampion- looks like your suggestion worked. Can you make an answer out of that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by [@AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750492/achampion), this

```
         elif i+j != target:
            print (i,j)
            return False
```

will exit the function on the first wrong result. Remove the `return False` to continue searching and only `return False` at the end.

---

Your algorithm works, as would AChampions itertools.combination approach, but using a set of all numbers and checking half of the numbers if they satisfy the condition

```
 (targetnumber - aktualnumber) in all_numbers
```

is much faster:

```
import random

random.seed(a=13, version=2)
random_numbers = random.sample(range(1,1000001), k=10000) # fix numbers

def pair_exists(nums, target):
    first_half = nums[:len(nums)//2] # even number of elements in nums
    all_nums = set(nums) # use a set for speed reasons

    for num in first_half:
        if target - num in all_nums and target - num != num:
            print(num, target - num)
            return True

    return False

print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 38109)) # True for me
print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 2))  # always False
```

Depending on the seed higher number might or might not be `True` while `2` can never be true due to range of 1...1000000 and the smallest two numbers adding up to 3.

---

Performance measurements:

```
With  sets
0.0125215
0.0157244

With  for loops
51.583881399999996
170.0219317

With  itertools
57.5434453
100.71193929999998
```

Code to replicate:

```
import random
from itertools import combinations

def pair_exists(nums, target):
    first_half = nums[:len(nums)//2] # even number of elements in nums
    all_nums = set(nums) # use a set for speed reasons

    for num in first_half:
        if target - num in all_nums and target - num != num:
            # print(num, target - num)
            return True
    return False

def pair_exists_itertools(nums, target):
    for i, j in combinations(nums, r=2):
        if i != j and i + j == target:
            # print (i,j)
            return True
    return False

def pair_exists_forloops(nums, target):
    for i in nums:
        for j in nums:
            if i != j and i + j == target:
                # print (i,j)
                return True
    return False


random.seed(a=13, version=2)
random_numbers = random.sample(range(1,1000001), k=10000) # fix numbers

from timeit import timeit

def test_em(w, f):
    n = 10    # repeat only for 10 times to average measurements
    print("With ", w)
    print(timeit(lambda: f(random_numbers, 38109), number=n))
    print(timeit(lambda: f(random_numbers, 2), number=n))
    
for what, func in ( ("sets",      pair_exists), 
                    ("for loops", pair_exists_forloops), 
                    ("itertools", pair_exists_itertools)):
    test_em(what, func)
```

Answer (score -2):

At the place where you wrote this

random.sample(range(1000000),k=10000) # generate 10,000 random numbers in [1, 1,000,000)

try changing the code to random.sample(range(1, 1000000),k=10000)

Comment: …wut? What for?